# Endpoint returns 404 when using custom Express server

Tags: reactjs, url-routing, next.js

I have a Next.js app with two pages. My structure looks like the following:

```
/pages
    /index.js
    /city.js
```

I've created a custom server so that if the user goes to anything other than the home page it should render city.js. For example if you go to myapp.com/phl then the url should stay myapp.com/phl but it should render city.js. The same applies if you go to myapp.com/stl.

Here's my custom server:

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const url = require('url');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express();

        server.get('*', (request, response) => {
            return handler(request, response);
        });

        server.get('/:airportCode', (request, response) => {
            console.log('hello from the server');
            app.render( request, response, '/city', { ...request.query, ...request.params } );
        });

        server.listen(3000, error => {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
        });
    })
    .catch(exception => {
        console.error(exception.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

When I visit the home page it renders that page fine, but when I go to https://myapp.com/phl I get a 404. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch up your page handler with the asterisk page handler:

```js
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const url = require('url');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express();

        server.get('/:airportCode', (request, response) => {
            console.log('hello from the server');
            app.render( request, response, '/city', { ...request.query, ...request.params } );
        });

        server.get('*', (request, response) => {
            return handler(request, response);
        });

        server.listen(3000, error => {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:3000');
        });
    })
    .catch(exception => {
        console.error(exception.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

The function of asterisk is like a fallback for any path that isn't handled by the previous function.

Comment: So the asterisk page handler has to always come last?